# WebClient class missing from Apache CXF?

Tags: java, apache, jax-rs, cxf

I am current building a JAX-RS client using Apache CXF version 3.1.11. I have been looking at some simple examples online and it appears the WebClient class has gone missing.

See the example code below that I found online.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
             JsonMappingException, IOException {
    WebClient client = WebClient
            .create("http://localhost:8080/",
                    Collections.singletonList(new JacksonJsonProvider()))
            .path("test").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    Message message = client.get(Message.class);
    System.out.println("Message recieved : " + message);
}
```

I cannot find the WebClient class anywhere in the code and im using the following maven dependencies.

- cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
- cxf-rt-transports-http
- cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty

Please could someone confirm if I am missing a dependency or if WebClient has been removed from version 3.1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure about specific provider implementation, you can use classes which are standar parts of *JAX-RS* instead, which are duo *`Client`* and *`WebTarget`*. But for marshalling things, sure, you probably still need specific dependency configured, either manually or it's been already provided by the *Apache CXF*.

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    WebTarget target = client
            .target("http://localhost:8080/");
    Response response = target.request().get();
    Message message = client.readEntity(Message.class);
     /*
     // now.. process the message
     for (Message message : message.get...) {.. }
    */
    response.close(); // close connections.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cxf-rt-frontend-**jaxrs** instead of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws